# Сравнительный оборот или придаточное?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, сравнительный-оборот, придаточное-предложение

***Он ведет себя(,) как женщина при ПМС.***

Запятую я бы не поставил, так как оборот имеет значения обстоятельства. Раньше и вопроса бы не возникло. Но вот загвоздка: "как женщина при ПМС" — разве не неполное придаточное сравнения, которое запятой все таки выделяется? "при ПМС" — обстоятельство, которое зависит от пропущенного сказуемого. Можем переделать: "Ведет себя, как женщина ведет себя при ПМС".

Теперь я и не уверен, нужна ли там запятая или нет? Работает ли тут правило, что оборот имеет значения образа действия или это неполное предложение, на которое это правило не распространяется?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Игорь.  Вот проходила мимо и задержала внимание на вашем вопросе.  Ну как было не зайти и  вас не поддержать!  Кажется, я понимаю, о чем вы спрашиваете, и попробую ответить.

Удивительные люди – наши пользователи языка, ну ни шагу  без правил ступить не могут и всегда толкуют их однозначно, а вот Розенталь предупреждал, что не надо так делать.  Как будто знаки препинания для того существуют, чтобы правила точно исполнялись.  Правила, конечно, святое дело, да только решать задачи по пунктуации лучше исходя из чувства языка.  А если уж есть решение, то и правило найдется.

**ОТВЕТ НА ВОПРОС**

1. Нужна ли запятая?  Допустим, я как автор решаю обособить оборот. Почему? Я ставлю ударение на глагол, и тогда требуется обособление:  **(1) Он ведЁт себя, как  женщина при ПМС.** Но при другой расстановке ударений я бы не стала обособлять  тот же самый оборот:  **(2) Он ведёт себя как  жЕнщина при ПМС,  а это утомлЯет.**
2. Нет, скажут мои критики, так низзя!  Здесь (по Розенталю)  нельзя обособлять  сравнительный оборот, так как без него «сказуемое не выражает необходимого смысла».
   Что ответить? А у меня  в предложении (1)  не сравнительный оборот, а неполное сравнительное придаточное с пропущенным сказуемым: Он ведЁт себя, как  (ведет себя) женщина при ПМС.  А вот в предложении (1)  это необособленный сравнительный оборот.
3. А разве такое возможно? Вполне. Вот пример из предыдущего ответа. Полное придаточное: Светское мнение было бы то, что он ведет себя, как ведут себя все молодые люди.
   Не полное придаточное:  Светское мнение было бы то, что он ведЁт себя, как все молодые люди.
   Сравнительный оборот: Светское мнение было бы то, что он ведет себя все молодые лЮди.
4. Но не каждое неполное сравнительное придаточное можно представить в виде оборота, например: Существование его заключено в эту тесную программу, как яйцо (заключено) в скорлупу (Чехов).   Здесь без запятой не обойтись, так как предложная форма «в скорлупу»  не определяет слово яйцо, этой формой управляет пропущенный глагол.

В нашем же случае  (как  женщина при ПМС) **разные толкования возможны:**  форма «при ПМС» может быть и **обстоятельством**  при пропущенном глаголе (неполное придаточное),  и  **обстоятельственным определением** при существительном (сравнительный оборот).

**ПРИМЕРЫ**

Итак,  ревнители правил говорят: не положено  перед оборотом  ставить запятую! А вот писатели их не слушают и иногда  обособляют оборот, например:

Ему выпало быть царем, и ребята с удивлением увидели, что он ведЁт себя, **как настоящий цАрь:** одних назначил своими телохранителями, других домоправителями, третьих осведомителями — никто не остался без дела. [М. Л. Гаспаров (1998)]

В целом он ведЁт себя, **как сумасшЕдший**, но ничем не выделяется на улице. [В. В. Лорченков, 2013]

Но и  не обособляется оборот довольно часто,  в том числе и распространенный оборот, например:
Впрочем, иногда он ведет себя **как парень вполне терпИмый и даже общИтельный**, показывает пародии, травит анекдоты... [Владимир Рецептер. (1993)]

В этих примерах  авторы явно ориентируются на расстановку ударений, а это зависит от структуры предложения. В общем, как слышат, так и пишут.

Answer (score 2):

Устойчивое сочетание ВЕДЁТ СЕБЯ практически не употребляется самостоятельно и требует главной смысловой части, тесно связанной с выражением ВЕДЁТ СЕБЯ и образующей с ним сказуемое. Запятая не ставится, даже если присоединяется выражение с КАК (можно условно заменить его формой существительного в творительном падеже - *ведёт себя женщиной*.

Из Нацкорпуса РЯ:

***Зяме, дурачку, это бы проглотить, девчонка всё-таки, а он полез в бутылку, поставил вопрос в райкоме: мол, Сташенок ведёт себя как аристократка из института благородных девиц.*** [Анатолий Рыбаков. Тяжелый песок (1975-1977)]

***Широкое чувство: Михайлов и ведёт себя как старожил ― просит кофе, прохаживается, привычно и со знанием роется на книжной полке.*** [Владимир Маканин. Отдушина (1977)]

Если используется придаточное предложение, в котором повторяется ВЕДЁТ СЕБЯ, то запятая ставится:

***Светское мнение было бы то, что он ведет себя, как ведут себя все молодые люди.*** [Л. Н. Толстой. Анна Каренина (1878)] - пример из Нацкорпуса РЯ.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а как доказать, что этот оборот - не придаточное? По-моему, он как раз придаточным является или я не прав?

Answer (score 2):

Выражение "вести себя" не имеет *законченного смысла* и потому не является полным сказуемым - таковым здесь выступает выражение "ведёт себя как женщина..." (ср. "...подобно женщине..."). Запятой быть **не** должно.

Самым распространённым учебным примером, ближайшим к теме вопроса, стало "**держится как хозяйка**" - его легко найти гуглом на множестве страниц, но берут его (включая "Грамоту", которая не сослалась на источник) из Справочника *Розенталя* по пунктуации:
https://ik-ptz.ru/diktanty-po-russkomu-yazyku--2-klass/ya-govoryu-kak-literator-spravochnik-po-punktuacii---rozental-d-e.html

> [запятая перед сравн. оборотом с "как" не ставится] ...если оборот образует
> именную часть составного сказуемого или по смыслу тесно связан со
> сказуемым (обычно в этих случаях сказуемое не имеет законченного
> смысла без сравнительного оборота).
> ***Она держится как хозяйка.*** (Если взять сказуемое «держится » без оборота «как хозяйка », то получается «она держится », и можно
> подумать, что она держится за что-то.)

Comment: Извините, если говорю глупости, но ведь у Розенталя речь идет именно про обороты, а не придаточные сравнения? "При ПМС" - это разве не обстоятельство?